# Retrieving contents of DragDrop EventArgs for an Embedded MSG attachment from Outlook is dragged onto a control

Tags: c#, .net, drag-and-drop, outlook

I have an application where files from the file system, emails from Outlook, or attachments from Outlook are dragged and dropped and the code then saves these in file system folders for uploading into SharePoint at a later time.

This is all fine apart from when I need to identify the contents of an attachment which is an email (*i.e. an email attachment on an email - embedded MSG*) where the **FileContents** are null. Is there any way I can access the content of the email for saving as a .msg file?

The following code snippet creates a `MemoryStream` correctly for attachments that aren't emails but is null for email types:

```
void DoDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var memoryStream = (MemoryStream) eventArgs.Data.GetData("FileContents", true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce this behavior. I used your above sample code and it works perfectly dragging embedded MSGs from the Explorer preview pane or the Inspector window. There must be something you're not sharing with us regarding the embedded MSG. [What is the attachment type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.attachment.type.aspx)?

I also suggest you [review the CodeProject sample for Outlook Drag-n-Drop](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28209/Outlook-Drag-and-Drop-in-C). Your sample code doesn't consider when multiple items are dropped onto the application - it will only take the first item if the user selects (2) attachments, (3) emails, (5) files, etc.

Comment: I'm coming back to this code now as the problem has raised its head again. The sample code above was part of a prototype. The actual code deals with multiple files. This happens if I create a sample email and attach it in a email to myself so I'm not sure what the differences are. I'll investigate the attachment type.

Answer (score 0):

I have an extended listbox control i vb.net that handles drag and drop operations including emails from Outlook. I have the same problem as you indicated in your original post. When dropping attachments that are made up of embedded .msg files, GetData returns FileContents that are null. For the time being, I simply display a message to the user indicating that they should try dropping the attachment on the desktop first then drag it to the application. This seems to work as the Windows OS takes care of extracting the data and storing it as a .msg file (which drags and drops correctly by itself).

I have also found some c# examples on how to do this but have been unsuccessful in re-creating them in vb.net. The most helpful was on codeproject.com and was called "Outlook Drag and Drop in C#" by David Ewen, 28 Jul 2008. It deals with both multiple attachments and attachments that are outlook messages. Since it is written in C#, perhaps you may find it of some use.

I know I am breaking the rules by asking, but if you have found a better resolution than what I am offering I would be interested.

Comment: If you have your own questions, its perfectly valid to post them.  Otherwise, consider star-ing this question and follow-up later.  You may also post your 'update request' as a commont on the question itself.  Welcome to the site!